# VIM: How to list all key mappings in the current buffer for a specified plugin

Tags: vim, macvim

I know how to use `nmap`, `imap` and so on to view all key mappings in vim, and how to list which action is bound to a given key binding. But sometimes I want to have a quick look at all key bindings for a given plugin, is there a quick way to do this? I don't want to list all keybindings and search them page by page.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `:help pluginname`

Comment: But the default config could be changed according filetype, customisation and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a command which get the mappings of a specific plugin in a separate window:

```
:let pluginName=".vimrc" | let cmdMap="map"
:redir => output | silent execute "verbose ".cmdMap | redir END | new | put=output | execute 'v/^.*\n.*'.escape(pluginName,'./').'/d'
```

1. In the first line, change the variable `pluginName` with any scriptname and `cmdMap` with any map command.(*Input*)
2. In the second line, execute the command which will parse the output.(*Result*)

---

You can still map those commands or create a function to get the input from user.

**Edit:**

To enlarge the use of other mappings commands (like `map!`) it would be more reliable to use a register name:

```
:redir @z | silent execute "verbose ".cmdMap | redir END | new | put z | execute 'v/^.*\n.*'.escape(pluginName,'./').'/d'
```

Comment: You'll need to check `map!` as well as `map` won't return insert-mode and command-mode mappings.

Comment: With a newer vim you can use `execute()`  and `:filter` instead of `:redir`. e.g. `command! -nargs=+ Map let map = call({pat, mode -> execute('filter '.pat.' verbose '.(mode=~'^.$'?mode.'map':mode))}, [<f-args>] + ['nmap']) | new | setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile | silent! exe 'pu=map'| silent! keeppat v/./d_ | 1 | silent! unlet map`, execute via: `Map unimpaired n`